# How do I implement a on hover effect for kivy buttons?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to implement an on-hover effect for this Windows desktop app but can't seem to find a working solution... (when the mouse moves over the buttons id like to change the color of the buttons) Here is the code I've got for the screen using the buttons, I'm using Kivy 2.2.0 if you need any more code please ask... :)

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    program_names = {
        'name1': 'program 1',
        'name2': 'program 2',
        'name3': 'program 3',
        'name4': 'program 4'
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 0.1)

    def update_labels(self, *args):
        store = JsonStore('data.json')

        program_name_values = {
            key: store1.get(key)['program_name'] if key in store1 else default_value
            for key, default_value in self.program_names.items()
        }

        self.ids.btn_1.text = program_name_values['name1']
        self.ids.btn_2.text = program_name_values['name2']
        self.ids.btn_3.text = program_name_values['name3']
        self.ids.btn_4.text = program_name_values['name4']
```

Here is the kv file code for the buttons

```
Button:
        id: btn_1
        background_color: (0.043, 0.478, 0.769, 1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        pos: 0, 500
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 80
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 635
        font_size: 30
        text: ""
        on_release:
            root.open_program_1()

    Button:
        id: btn_2
        background_color: (0.043, 0.478, 0.769, 1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        pos: 0, 390
        size_hint_y: None
        height:80
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 635
        font_size: 30
        text: ""
        on_release:
            root.open_program_2()

    Button:
        id: btn_3
        background_color: (0.043, 0.478, 0.769, 1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        pos: 0, 280
        size_hint_y: None
        height:80
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 635
        font_size: 30
        text: ""
        on_release:
            root.open_program_3()

    Button:
        id: btn_4
        background_color: (0.043, 0.478, 0.769, 1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        pos: 0, 170
        size_hint_y: None
        height:80
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 635
        font_size: 30
        text: ""
        on_release:
            root.open_program_4()
```